# Grab git commit ID from URL

Tags: php, git, rss, gitlab, atom-feed

I'm trying to parse an atom feed from Gitlab on my project to display a version history on my website. I do plan on caching my results per 30 minutes but right now I'm trying to extract the commit ID straight from the URL provided in the feed.

The ID provided for the commit in the feed is a URL:

```
https://gitlab.com/username/project/commit/c8c6ad918939d6fae60e1369b28b859390a32d56
```

To grab the simplified version of the actual commit, first I exploded the URL by `/` then selected the last index using `end()`. If I'm correct, the commit id will always be at the end of the URL so this should work on any project on gitlab (correct me if I'm wrong please).

```
$id = explode('/', $feed->id); // Explode the URL into an array

$commit  = substr(end($id), 0, 9); // Cut the string, select 

echo $commit, '<br>';
```

This gives me a list of all commits for my project. The commit id is pretty and not the long hash as intended.

**This question here is, am I doing the right thing? Could I be doing something better?**

---

If you're wondering how I got here, I first grabbed the RSS Atom feed from my projects commits section, then ran `file_get_contents()` on it and parsed the XML using `SimpleXMLElement`. After that I simply used `foreach()` on the entry to loop through all commits.

I'm going to cache the file output for performance so scratch that off your mind. I really want to know if I'm doing this correctly and efficiently and what method you would use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well why not hit it all with one line of regex ? Something like:

```
 preg_match_all("(\/[a-f0-9]{9})",$inputXmlFeed, $urls);
```

The $urls variable should now have a list of the commit hashes you are looking for without parsing or looping unless you need something other than the commit reference.

Comment: I've never truly understood regex which is why I didn't take this approach.

Comment: Perfect then just stick with what you did. In my opinion it's a fair solution (bit loopy though), and you can build above it when you need more information from the XML response.